# I uninstalled mongodb directly from the control panel，how can I remove it completely now？

Tags: mongodb

I thought that mongodb could be uninstalled directly from the control panel, but after I did this, I found that this was not the case, so what should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply delete folder of MonogDB binaries and data folder.

If you installed MongoDB as service you can remove it with these command lines:

```
sc stop <service name>
sc config <service name> start=disabled
sc delete <service name>
```